# Retrieving keys from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, key, nsdictionary

I'm having a hard time managing to pull anything out of a JSON response when querying TMDb. Despite spending most of the weekend searching these forums and others, I am no nearer a solution.

In my header file I have:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary * fetchedData;
```

The dictionary is populating correctly, since the first part of the JSON response looks like this when I use:

```
NSLog(@"fetchedData: %@", fetchedData);


fetchedData: {
  page = 1;
  results = (
    {
      adult = 0;
      id = 1245;
      "known_for" = (
        {
          adult = 0;
          "backdroppath" = "/hbn46fQaRmlpBuUrEiFqv0GDL6Y.jpg";
          "genreids" = ( 878, 28, 12 );
          id = 24428;
          "mediatype" = movie;
          "original_language" = en;
          "original_title" = "The Avengers";
```

I've been trying numerous ways to retrieve all instances of "original_title" (or any of the keys) in the response, but I have no hair left to pull out when every attempt is returning NULL, so any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Show the code for one of your attempts. How are you dealing with the arrays?

Comment: You are not getting a valid JSON format. First validate you JSON string.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",[yourDict allKeys]);` return all key array.

Comment: How are you populating `fetchedData` ? Are you using something like `fetchedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];` ?

Comment: I up voted your question.SO please tick and up vote my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSString *title = fetchedData[@"results"][0][@"known_for"][0][@"original_title"];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just as I hoped it would.  The problem I have is that both answers came up with the right result - can I mark both answers as the answer?

Comment: Actually I was first, but it is not very important for me. I just helped.

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from Response

I think fetchedData is dictionary.So

```
NSString *strOriginalTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[[fetchedData valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"known_for"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"original_title"];

      //OR By getting data step by step

NSArray *arrayResults = [fetchedData valueForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[arrayResults objectAtIndex:0]  copy];
NSArray *arrayKnownFor = [dict valueForKey@"known_for"] copy];
NSString *strOriginalTitle = [arrayKnownFor objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"original_title"];
NSLog(@"The original_title is - %@",strOriginalTitle);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just as I hoped it would.  The problem I have is that both answers came up with the right result - can I mark both answers as the answer?

Comment: My answer is showing you in step by step process as well as one line process.So please tick my answer and up vote my answer.Thank you.

Comment: Please tick and up vote my answer as i explained you very neatly and understandably.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I had tried to upvote previously but it said I needed 15 rep.  Now I do have that, I have done so.  Thanks.